# How to use Bower "source mapping" with build tools?

Tags: dependency-management, bower, package-managers

Bower's [documentation section on "Consuming a package"](https://github.com/bower/bower#consuming-a-package) says:

> Bower also makes available a source mapping. This can be used by build tools to easily consume Bower packages.

Then it exemplifies the JSON that you can output with a simple command:

```
{
  "backbone": "bower_components/backbone/index.js",
  "jquery": "bower_components/jquery/index.js",
  "underscore": "bower_components/underscore/index.js"
}
```

I understand what's going on here ... but I don't really understand what it's for, i.e. how to use it.

I haven't been able to find examples of people using such a source map, and it's not easily apparent to me what the Bower docs are suggesting. I'm wondering *how* this Bower-generated JSON can be used by build tools to consume packages, easily.

Does anybody know? Has anybody done this or seen it done?

Comment: I guess somebody downvoted this question? I'd be interested in hearing why.

Answer (score 2):

One of the main uses (at least as far as I know) for using the list --paths option and seeing the mapping is for build tools - as the docs suggest.  It'd be good if they gave an example, but I can here.

So say you're using Bower to manage front-end dependencies but you're using Grunt to build your site/app.  How do you reconcile the two? Bower installs dependencies in a default root like 'app/_bower_components/packageName/' ie a path you'd never want to use in production or probably even development because its awkward and may refer to an un-minified version of the package/library JS.

Grunt has tasks like 'uglify' that take a given JS file and minify and mangle it down to a much smaller size, useful for production sites. In Grunt you might write a task like this:

```
        uglify: {
        modernizr: {
            files: {
                'javascripts/modernizr.min.js': 'app/_bower_components/modernizr/modernizr.js'
            }
        }
```

This uses the mapping Bower provided in the second argument (ie points to the Bower source) and outputs the uglified output to the first argument (in this case javascripts/modernizr.min.js) for production purposes.

In this sense your build tool, Grunt, 'consumes' your Bower packages and copies & minifys them for your site.  This way as long as your Uglify task has the right path, you can use Bower to update/manage your dependencies and you wont directly edit the source. So if for instance there's a new version of JQuery you just update it via Bower and shouldn't need to do anything else; no manual copying, no editing.